# Howto define list of function with constrained parameters

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I need to design a type `MatchingFunc` that given a list of types, provides a list of functions with matching parameters that returns the provided types.

I can get the list of valid functions, but what does not work is the constraint on parameters.

For example if the first functions is like `(a: 1, b: 2) => 3` the second function could be with the same parameters or with extended one like `(a: 1, b: 2, c: 3)` (the third should extend the second one and so forth).

The type as designed accepts any parameters.
Is they re a way to achieve what i want?

```js
type Func <P extends any [] = any [], R = any> = (...p: P) => R
type Tail <L extends any []> = L extends [any, ...infer R] ? R : never
type Last <L extends any []> = L [Tail <L> ['length']]

type MatchingFunc <Rets extends any [], FF extends Func [] = []> =
  Rets extends [] ? FF :
  Last <FF> extends Func <infer P> ? 
    MatchingFunc <Tail <Rets>, [...FF, Func <[...P, ...any []], Rets [0]>]> :
    MatchingFunc <Tail <Rets>, [...FF, Func <any [], Rets [0]>]>

declare function use <FF extends MatchingFunc <[string, boolean]>> (...ff: FF): any

const test = use (
  (a: string, b: number) => a,
  (a: number, b: string) => !a, // should break
)
```

Edit:
Based on the comment of @jcalz i realized that the description of the type wasn't clear.

One clear use case of it will be the [ramda function converge](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#converge)

Converge for one use case could be defined as such

```
const func = converge ((a: number, b: string) => Symbol.for (b + a), [
  (a: number, b: number) => a + b, // returns number for a in converging function
  (a: number, b: number, c: string) => c + a + b, // returns string for b in...
])
```

The return types of the list of functions are the inputs of the first function.

`typeof func` will then be `(a: number, b: number, c: string) => symbol` which contains the parameters of the function in the list with the greater length and returns the type of the first function.

The type `MatchingFunc` is then defined as a type that given a list of return type (the argument of the converging function) produce a list of the same length of functions that have matching parameters.

The type provided here ensures two things:

- that the functions returns the exepected types
- that we have precisely the number of functions of the length of the provided return types

What is missing, is the constrained parameters of those functions that must be restricted to matching ones i.e.:
`[a: 1, b: 2]` matches `[]`, `[a: 1]`, `[a: 1, b: 2, c: 3]` but does not match `[a: 2]`, `[a: 1, b: 1]` ...

[playground](https://tsplay.dev/mL29Vw)

Comment: What would the return type of the last function be then? Anything? What is the return type of `use` supposed to be?

Comment: Are you okay manually annotating the callback parameters?  If so then maybe [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/wgQrbm) will work for you.  If you want me to write that up as an answer I can, just comment and mention @jcalz to notify me.  If not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz still need to understand your solution but seems to work like a charm. What will be even better if we do not need to specify types of the parameters of the first functions in the other functions - as those will always be of the same type. ```const goodTest = use(
  (a: string, b: number) => a,
  (a, b, c: string) => c.length > b, //...```but even without yep seems a fine solution enough - many thanks - i'll probably understand your solution better with your full answer ;)

Comment: @jcalz the bit i do not get is ```[unknown, ...FF] extends { [K in I]: (...args: infer A) => infer R }``` why prepending `unknwon`  ?

Comment: oups the extra parameters in the functions is not the return of the previous function @jcalz - the retrun types of each functions is specified before and the parameters of each functions have to match (the resulting function will use the parameters of ths longest function)

The aim at first was to design a type for the `allPass` [function in ramda](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#allPass) and i wanted to make it more general to accept various returning type to be used in a function like `ifElse` [link](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#ifElse)

Comment: I don’t know what `allPass` or `ifElse` is; if that’s necessary to understand the question then maybe you should tag the question with ramda? Otherwise could you [edit] the question to explain your goal more clearly and give some use cases with a [mre]?

Comment: @jcalz hopefully it is more clear

Comment: So [here](https://tsplay.dev/WvG84w) is the best I can do.  Conceptually it's not so bad to write the call signature, but the compiler is apparently completely unable to infer the parameters to the functions from what you pass in.  I have to jump through crazy type hoops to make something like the desired inference happen, and then there are some interesting edge cases, and it is probably fragile in weird ways.  I could maybe write this up as an answer, if you think it works for you, but YUCK.  Let me know.

Comment: Definitly going through loop and crazy types
but that waorks fine thank you

Comment: @jcalz why do you need in the type of `fns` in the definition of `converge` to use `[...F] extends`  instead of `F extends`  o_O?
`F` is defined as an array so i do not get the necessity of this (and i've tried writing it `F extends` and indeed don't work)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248641/discussion-between-zedryas-and-jcalz).

Comment: Chat scares me, I feel like it's a dark alley where someone can assault me.  I'd rather stay here.  I don't know that I feel up to explaining every little bit of my solution in an answer; it would be twenty pages long!  The quick answer to why `[...F] extends` is that it gives the compiler a hint that you want `F` to be inferred as a tuple type and not as an unordered arbitrary length array.

Comment: no worries was just using chat as indicated by SO.
and lol no worries for the full explanation i will be happy to discovered it even just a little bit contextualized @jcalz ;)

Comment: @jcalz when you have the time i would love to see youre solution written ;)